# Yoast SEO Plugin not recognising content from the Wordpress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I have developed a Wordpress website recently and used all the contents in the template itself. And all the pages and posts fields of WP admin is empty lacking content.

So my content is present in my template and not in the post and pages field.

I used Yoast SEO for this website and when checking with pages in WPadmin. No content is recognized and thus my SEO score is very low. But my content is present in the template which will be displayed in live also.

Example: I want to optimize home page and let the content be 300 words present along with template itself. No when i use Yoast plugin it is not recognizing the content from the template and says: " there is low volume of content in the home page" like this.

Can any one suggest me in solving this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yoast SEO can only give you a score based on DB content that it can read. That being said, just because Yoast SEO can't see your content doesn't mean that search engines can't. Unfortunately, unless you get your content out of the template and into WordPress, your Yoast score will never improve.

I'd recommend (if possible) to try to get that content into WordPress. It's just not best practice to hard-code content into template files. Consider using Custom Fields if you have specialized content that won't work in the WYSIWYG.