# Yoast SEO (Wordpress) is not reading my custom page content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

Recently i have taken to using Wordpress for certain CMS tools.

I am a HTML/PHP/JS guy so prefer to code it all my self, however, yoast plugin doesnt see the content that is placed directly in the core template file.

The page is looking great, however id idealy like to have some form of code that allows the content to be seen (if possible)
I dont mind placing the code in the page using wordpress rather than hardcoding in the core template, but when i do, nothing shows.

So far things are working great, but this is a problem as id rather keep it clean and use wordpress's page setup.

I have the header/footer setup using the `<?php get_header(); ?>` function.
Is there a "content" option?

anyone having a similar problem? anyone shed some light?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? our site has a lot of its contents in templates, and Yoast don't read template contents. [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289975/yoast-seo-plugin-not-recognising-content-from-the-wordpress-template) I haven't found a good solution for this.